# Media query not working to swap out background image

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Gosh not even sure how to ask this.  I have a slideshow, with currently only one slide, that displays the background main image of my website.  I'm trying to create a media query that will swap out the large background for another image, better suited for mobile.  I "seem" to have created a query that's working but it doesn't replace the main image, it loads my new image "behind" the main image.  ???

Here is the HTML..

```
<div id="home">                 
  <div class="tp-banner-container">
    <div class="tp-banner" >                
      <ul>
          <!-- THE FIRST SLIDE -->
            <li data-transition="zoomout" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="700">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />

}
                            <!-- THE CAPTIONS IN THIS SLIDE -->
                            <div class="caption big-text lft"  
                                 data-x="center" 
                                 data-y="350"
                                width="10px" 
                                 data-speed="700" 
                                 data-start="700" 
                                 data-easing="easeOutExpo">
                                    <div class="big-text"><span4>YOUR IDEAS REALIZED</span4></br><div><a class="button3 scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT US</a></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is my media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 414px) {
.tp-banner-container .tp-banner >ul >li .tp-bgimg:nth-child(1) {
        background:url('../images/1_mobile.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}}
```

According to the inspector on my browser, it "seems" like it worked but loads behind the main image.  Hopefully you can see this screen capture...

[image]

Anyone know what I need to do to make the mobile background replace the one the slideshow is trying to load?  Any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your snippet is NOT a media query. Is there more to it you're not posting?

Comment: oh i see the complete query in your image. What is the width of the screen in pixels?

Comment: Just updated that, thanks :)  Have the info you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in the image(and its difficult to really know for certain from an image) you have two background-image css properties on the same element, one inline in the html, and one in the media query.  Whenever there are two conflicting css properties, the inline one **always** takes precedence.  If you cannot change the inline background-image property, try adding `!important` to the media query, but that may not work either.  Cant check myself on an image.  But that is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there's javascript happening on it, you may need to override each background attribute individually as opposed to just using a single line "background" attribute.

Comment: I honestly don't know.